# Python login program

Tags: python, security, authentication, passwords

I'm writing a login program in Python,it takes the usernames and the passwords,and stores it for each user in a separate .txt file.
I can already register,the program creates the file,but i can't login.
Here's the code:

```
###############
import getpass
import time
ussr=False
passwd1=False
acc=False
notin=False
reg=False
t=[]
###############
#f;a;;b;c;d;z;;;;;
###############
def bor():
    global acc
    print("1-->Login")
    print("2-->Register")
    a=int(input("B/R: "))
    if  a==1:
        acc=True
    if a==2:
        acc=False

def ACCOUNT():
    if acc==True:
        login()
    if acc==False:
        register()

def file():
    global jel
    f=open(z,"r")
    sor=f.read()
    jel=sor.strip().split()
    for s in jel:
        t.append(s)
    f.close()


def register():
    global reg
    reg=True
    global z
    b=input("Username: ")
    c=getpass.getpass('Passwd')
    z=input("Filename(.txt!):")
    f2=open(z,"w")
    f2.close()
    f=open(z,"r+")
    if b not in f:
        notin=True
    f.close
    if notin==True:
        f1=open(z,"a")
        f1.write(b)
        f1.write(c)
        f1.close
    if notin==False:
        print("This username is already taken")
        exit

def login():
    global usr
    global passwd
    global passwd1
    global ussr
    global z
    usr=input("Username: ")
    passwd=getpass.getpass('Password')
    z=input("Filename(.txt!):")
    for i in t:
        if usr==i:
            ussr=True
        if passwd==i:
            passwd1=True

def check():
    if reg==True:
        exit
    if ussr==True and passwd1==True:
        print("Login succesful")
        time.sleep(12)
    if ussr==True and passwd1==False:
        print("Wrong password")
    if ussr==False and passwd1==True:
        print("Wrong username")





bor()
ACCOUNT()
file()
check()
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: you havent called the login()

Comment: It's because  the ACCOUNT function calls it,so i don't need to.If i call it,it will ask the user to login,even if the want to register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please avoid using global variables, and start programming more "pythonic". Begin using a class object and function arguments. 
Really, global variables are BAD.

Then:

```
def ACCOUNT():
    if acc==True:
        login()
    if acc==False:
        register()
```

Is an horrible statement.

```
def ACCOUNT(acc):
   if acc: login() 
   else: register()
```

is way better.

You have to consider "if, else, elif", when you write conditions:

```
if a == 1: 
   doSomething()
elif a == 2:
   doSomethingElse()
else:
   doAnotherThing()
```

To be clear, unless you need to check the variable type, generally "if varname" is ok (it will return false if an object is empty, or if a boolean value is equal to False and None as well).

If you have to check on a boolean value, you generally don't have to specify the condition you're looking for.

"if not a" is *more pythonic* than "if a == False" (but, again, it will match "None" as well and not just "False"!!)

And tell yourself, everytime you declare a global variable: "**I am doing something wrong, and there's for sure a better way to do this**.

You can pass variables as function arguments:

```
def sumFunction(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 + arg2
```

and you can declare classes, to store variables, functions that work on the same task, and start programming better:

```
class Authentication():
    def __init__(self):
        # the __init__ class method is run everytime the function is istantiated
        self.example = 'I am an example'

    def Login(self, username, password):
        # this will do authentication things with
        # username and password variables, that lives
        # ONLY in this function (namespace)

    def Register(self, username, password):
        # do register things
```

you can then istantiate the class Authentication like this

```
auth = Authentication()
```

and use the instance as you wish:

```
auth.Login(username, password)
auth.Register(username, password)
```

"self" is the class namespace, viewed from itself. 
You can store whatever you like in it, and you can call sub-functions in class from one to another, prepending the "self." prefix

In the example I have provided, you can access the "I am an example text" in this way:

```
>>> x = Authentication()
>>> x.example
'I am an example'
```

Finally, when you declare a class method (a function in a class), you always have to specify "self" at first argument, but you don't need to pass it when calling the method from the outside (so a class method with 3 arguments: (self, arg1, arg2), will expect TWO arguments to work, just arg1 and arg2.

**Read more, write less**, good luck.